# Fetch multiple rows from SQL in PHP foreach item in array

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to request an array of IDs, to return each row with that ID, and push each into an Array `$finalArray`

But only the first result from the Query will output, and at the second `foreach`, it skips the `while` loop.

I have this working in another script, so I don't understand where it's going wrong.

The `$arrayItems` is an array containing: `"home, info"`

```
 $finalArray = array(); 
 foreach ($arrayItems as $UID_get)
 {
     $Query =   "SELECT * 
                FROM items
                WHERE (uid = '" . cleanQuery($UID_get) . "' )
                ORDER BY uid";

  if($Result = $mysqli->query($Query))
  {
        print_r($UID_get);
        echo "<BR><-><BR>";

      while ($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        array_push($finalArray , $Row);
        print_r($finalArray );
        echo "<BR><><BR>";
      }
   } 
   else
   {
    echo '{ "returned" : "FAIL" }'; //. mysqli_connect_errno() . ' ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "<BR>";
   }
 }
```

(the cleanQuery is to escape and stripslashes)

What I'm trying to get is an array of multiple rows (after i json_encoded it, like:

```
{ "finalArray" : 
    { "home": 
        { "id":"1",
          "created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "css": "{ \"background-color\" : \"red\" }"
        } 
    }, 
    { "info": 
        { "id":"2",
          "created":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "css":"{ \"background-color\" : \"blue\" }"
        } 
    } 
}
```

But that's after I get both, or more results from the db.

the `print_r($UID_get);` does print `info`, but then nothing..

So, why am I not getting the second row from `info`? I am essentially re-querying foreach $arrayItem right?

Comment: instead of `array_push`, try `$finalArray[]=$Row;`

Comment: That still doesn't get it into the while loop, it only does that for the first Result, and for the second `foreach`, it gets past the `if` but the `while` seems to be `false` or something..

Comment: can you please paste var_dump($arrayItems) ??

Comment: if your `$arrayItems` contains `"home, info"`, then it is single value of array. you might use explode() to get both home and info

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "home" [1]=> string(5) " info" }

Comment: Already did: $arrayItems = explode(",", $queryArray); Where `$queryArray = $_REQUEST['queryString']';

Comment: can you check into database table ? is there entries for `info`

Comment: Yes, there is, even if I make the second array entry 'home', it still WONT get past the while loop, which is the main problem...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19430/discussion-between-gbd-and-tryspace)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out... The leading space in the array, for the second item had to be trimmed with:

```
trim($UID_get);
```

Thanks GBD

Answer (score 0):

after fetching array from mysql resource, try executing the following function, by passing fetched array as parameter.(inside your while loop)

```
    function array_remove_indexes(&$arr)
    {
        $new_arr = array();
        foreach($arr as $name => $val)
        {
            if(!is_int($name))$new_arr[$name]=$val;
        }
        $arr = $new_arr;
    }
```